# React Native Redux Animate Height of view without knowing the original size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to animate a View with dynamic height like an accordion menu.

```
class Accordeon extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ViewScale: new Animated.Value(0),
            chevronDeg: new Animated.Value(0),
            expanded: false,
            height: 0,
        };
    }
    
    render() {
        const ViewDegValue = this.state.ViewScale.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 50, 100],
            outputRange: ['0deg', '90deg', '180deg']
        });

        return(
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[accordionStyles.header]}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({expanded:!this.state.expanded});
                    
                        Animated.parallel ([
                            Animated.timing(
                                this.state.chevronDeg,
                                {
                                toValue: !this.state.expanded ? 0 : 100,
                                duration: 200,
                                }
                            ),
                            Animated.timing(
                                this.state.ViewScale,
                                {
                                    toValue: this.state.expanded ? 0 : 100,
                                    duration: 200,
                                }
                                )
                        ]).start();

                    }}
                >   
                    <Text
                        style={[accordionStyles.header__text, styles.headline__h2]}
                    >
                        {this.props.headerLabel}
                    </Text>
                    <Animated.View 
                        style={{
                            transform: [
                                {rotateZ: ViewDegValue}
                            ]
                        }}>
                            <FontAwesome 
                                iconStyle={[accordionStyles.header__icon,]} 
                                name={"chevron-down"}
                                size={30}
                            >
                            </FontAwesome>  
                    </Animated.View>
                    
                                        
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Animated.View 
                    onLayout={(event) => {
                        var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                        this.setState({height:height})
                    }}
                    style={[
                        this.state.expanded ? accordionStyles.content__hidden : accordionStyles.content__show,
                        accordionStyles.content,
                        {
                         **** this code below ****
                            // height: this.state.ViewScale.interpolate({
                            //     inputRange: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                            //     outputRange: [0, 75, 150, 225, this.state.height]
                            // }),
                            transform: [
                                {translateY: - this.state.height / 2},
                                {scaleY: this.state.ViewScale.interpolate({
                                    inputRange: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                                    outputRange: [0, .5, 0.75, 0.9, 1]
                                })},
                                {translateY: this.state.height / 2}
                            ]
                        } 
                    ]}
                >
                    {this.props.children}
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

and my problem is if activate this code the accordeon is not in full size just 224.*px because on layout cant gets the full size and if I set the height to auto.[image: height: auto] just scale the view then there is if the accordeon closed a giant gap between them because there is no 0 height set.[image: height:0 closed][image: height: 0 open] I won't put an absolute and opacity element of every accordeon anywhere that's no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my self the solution.
i add onLayout to the header and to the content but don't animate the height of the content of the whole component so the content has its original size but i have to set the initial headerHeight bigger then it is and on first load it sets it self to its original size. Thats no problem because the headerHeight is not dynamic only the contentHeight.

```
<Animated.View 
  style={[
    accordionStyles.accordeon,
    {height: this.state.ViewScale.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
      outputRange: [this.state.headerHeight, 75, 150, 225, this.state.headerHeight 
      + this.state.contentHeight]
    }),}
  ]}
>
```